# Euler classes of projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

The Euler classes of spheres $S^d$ is
$$
e(S^d)=1+(-1)^d.
$$

The Euler classes of real projective space ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})$ is
$$e({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=d+1 \mod 2.$$

The Euler classes of complex projective space ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{C}})$ is
$$e({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{C}}))=d+1.$$

The Euler classes of quaternion projective space ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{H}})$ is
$$e({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{H}}))=d+1.$$

> 1. Are my above statements correct? Can I derive these results more cleanly and uniformly in a systematic approach?
> 2. How can I relate these results to other characteristic classes?

Comment: There should be an argument in the beginning of Milnor-Stasheff that relates $TP^n$ to the tautological line bundle (over $\Bbb R$). IIRC this argument can be generalized to give you the structure of $TP^n$ (and in particular the Euler classes) over $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ as well. The less systematic (imo) to get this is just come up with CW-structures for these spaces and then compute homology. Everything you wrote looks correct to me. In general, Milnor-Stasheff is a good place to broaden your understanding on this subject.

Comment: The Euler class of an orientable manifold $M$, i.e. $e(TM)$, is equal to the Euler characteristic $\chi(M)$ of that manifold. You can check that what you have written is correct for the manifolds you consider. A reference for this is, again, Milnor-Stasheff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you somewhat confuse  Euler class and Euler characteristic. For example, Euler class is defined only for the  orientable manifolds, where the top cohomology group is Z, while Euler characteristic is defined for any manifold. (Half of the projective spaces are not orientable!)